# AppInitialize for Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I can't seem to find anything on this, but if I want to load static data in an Azure WCF application, I want to use something like AppInitialize?

I know AppInitialize works with IIS, but not Azure WebRoles.  What would the Azure equivalent be?

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Web-Roles, please see this blog-post:

[Hosting a WCF Service in an Azure Web Role with HTTP & TCP Endpoints](http://rickrainey.com/2013/08/30/hosting-a-wcf-service-in-an-azure-web-role-with-http-tcp-endpoints/)

If you ever have to implement a worker role that needs to host a WCF service, this is the way to go:

Azure Worker Roles use the *WorkerRole* class that is inherited from the *RoleEntryPoint* class to implement the three different life-time states of a  worker role:

```
 public abstract class RoleEntryPoint
  {
    public virtual bool OnStart()
    {
      return true;
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(-1);
    }

    public virtual void OnStop()
    {
    }
  }
```

You can fire up your WCF host within the Run() method.

I have written a blog-post that demonstrates how to create a WCF routing service that updates it's routes automatically using Azure Service Bus:

[Self updating WCF Routing Service on Windows Azure using CloudFx](http://www.awsomedevsigner.com/2013/08/31/self-updating-wcf-routing-service-windows-azure-using-cloudfx/)

UPDATE: The answer was completely out of the context of the question. Added a comment.

Comment: The blog post doesn't tell me what method I can hook in to.  Also, why have you explained RoleEntryPoint?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I completely confused concepts here. It was about 4PM in the morning. Sorry about that. If I add an *App_Code* folder to my web-role and add a class with a static *AppInitialize()* method to that folder, the static method is executed. I don't see any reason why this should not work in a Azure web-role - it's hosted using IIS.